# Ошибка RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

Tags: android, recyclerview

Пробовал отключать InstantRun, проверил все возможные ошибки но ничего не нашел. Вот код :

fragment

```
     public RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
ListFreindsAdapter mAdapter;
public RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;

private VKList<VKApiUserFull> list;

public FragmentAcount() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_acount, container, false);
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)v.findViewById(R.id.rview);
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    mAdapter = new ListFreindsAdapter(getActivity(), list = new VKList<>());
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    showFriends();

    return v;
}

private void showFriends() {
    final VKRequest request = VKApi.friends().get(VKParameters.from(VKApiConst.FIELDS, "first_name, last_name"));
    request.executeWithListener(new VKRequest.VKRequestListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(VKResponse response) {
            super.onComplete(response);
            list.clear();
            list.addAll((VKList<VKApiUserFull>) response.parsedModel);
            mAdapter.setNewList(list);
        }
    });
}
```

layout fragment

```
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rview"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

adapter

```
   public class ListFreindsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ListFreindsAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private VKList<VKApiUserFull> list;

    public ListFreindsAdapter(Context context, VKList<VKApiUserFull> list) {
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
    }

    public void setNewList(VKList<VKApiUserFull> list){
        this.list = list;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_freinds_recycler, parent, false);
        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.nameFriend.setText("A" + list.get(position).first_name.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
            return list == null ? 0 : list.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private TextView nameFriend;

        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            nameFriend = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.nameFriend);
        }
    }
}
```

layuot adapter

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nameFriend"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Эта ошибка возникает в тот момент когда `RecyclerView` пытается отрисовать себя, но при этом не имеет прикреплённого к нему адаптера. Эта ошибка относится к категории **некритичных** и может быть совершенно спокойно проигнорирована.

Но если это вас не устраивает попробуйте сделать следующее:

В момент инициализации и настройки `RecyclerView` создайте пустой адаптер и прикрепите его к `RecyclerView`. После загрузки данных добавьте данные в коллекцию, переданную в конструктор адаптера, затем уведомите его об изменении данных.

В коде это будет выглядеть так:

```
public class YourFragment extends Fragment{
    private VKList<VKApiUserFull> list;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_acount, container, false);
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)v.findViewById(R.id.rview);
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        mAdapter = new ListFreindsAdapter(getActivity(), list = new VKList<>());
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        showFriends();

        return v;
    }

    private void showFriends() {
        final VKRequest request = VKApi.friends().get(VKParameters.from(VKApiConst.FIELDS, "first_name, last_name"));
        request.executeWithListener(new VKRequest.VKRequestListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(VKResponse response) {
                super.onComplete(response);
                list.clear(); //если вам необходимо очищать список при каждом запросе
                list.addAll((VKList<VKApiUserFull>) response.parsedModel);
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        });
    }
}
```

---

**Важно:** не переприсваивайте `list`, а работайте только с данными внутри него. иначе `notifyDataSetChanged()` не отработает потому, что в объекте, ссылку которого вы передали в адаптер изменений не произошло, а произошла подмена ссылки внутри переменной `list` без изменения данных.

---

Если вдруг это произошло - есть 2 решения вышеперечисленной проблемы:

1.Создать метод в адаптере который заменяет коллекции с данными и обновляет себя.

```
public class ListFreindsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ListFreindsAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    public void setNewList(VKList<VKApiUserFull> list){
        this.list = list;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Вызвать этот метод необходимо когда появился новый экземпляр `VKList'a` таким образом:

```
mAdapter.setNewList((VKList<VKApiUserFull>) response.parsedModel);
```

2.Создать новый экземпляр адаптера и прикрепить его к `RecyclerView`:

```
ListFreindsAdapter mAdapter = new ListFreindsAdapter(getActivity(), list = new VKList<>());
mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

---

**UPD**

Путём долгих проб различных вариантов было установлено что `ConstraintLayout` не может быть контейнером для фрагментов. Вся проблема с отображение заключалась в этом.

Comment: Спасибо, очень развнернутый ответ, ошибка исчезла но в адаптер все ровно не попал. Вывожу в адаптере текст в консоль но ответа нет. И как вызвать из фрагмента из адаптера. Просто создавал обєкт так ` public RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter  = new ListFreindsAdapter(getContext(), list = new VKList<>());` и оно не видит методы внутри `ListFreindsAdapter`

Comment: @FediaCholak, обновил ответ, добавьте в адаптер метод из пункта 1 и во фрагменте создавать экземпляр адаптера необходимо способом, показанным в пункте 2

Comment: Спасибо, но как все таки запустить адаптер ? Точнее не могу ничего сделать внутри адаптера.

Comment: @FediaCholak не понимаю что именно у вас не получается. Обновите, пожалуйста, вопрос, с конкретным неработающим кодом.

Comment: Обновил вопрос. Проблема все та же. В RecyclerView Ничего не можу сделать, програма просто не заходит в него.

Comment: @FediaCholak проверьте, пожалуйста, точно ли у вас загружаются данные? В коде ошибок нет. Кроме как ненужный контекст внутри адаптера и вызов метода `setNewList()`. Заместо вызова нужно использовать `mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: Данные загружаются, в фрагменте они есть. А вот в адаптере даже проверить не  могу потому что нет никакой реакции на все что там делаю .

Answer (score 1):

Для тех кто еще столкнется с аналогичной проблемой в xml для recyclerview необходимо добавить атрибут app:layoutManager:

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
   android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager" />
```