# RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

Tags: java, android, json, android-fragment, recyclerview

начал изучать Андроид, дошел до серверов.Создал свой  [fake-json-server](https://my-json-server.typicode.com/Sorulai/MyMoviesPlaceholder/movies) для получения данных и вставки в `recycler`, который должен отображать список фильмов. Использовал библиотеки `retrofit` и `interceptor`. В итоге `interceptor` в логах показывает, что данные приложение считывает с сервера, но вылезает ошибка в recycler - `07-25 01:03:43.362 7766-7766/com.example.filmapp E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout`. Так же у меня присутствует `BottomNavigationView`, в котором  есть фрагменты Home и Favorite.Код для Favorite не написан, но на нем тоже происходит эта ошибка.

**FragmentFilm**

```
public class FragmentFilm extends Fragment {
private View rootView;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private List<FilmItem> filmItemList;
private FilmAdapter filmAdapter;



@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);


    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    filmItemList = new ArrayList<>();

    MovieApp.getInstance().movieService.getMovies().enqueue(new Callback<List<FilmJson>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<FilmJson>> call, Response<List<FilmJson>> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                recyclerView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewFilm);
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

                List<FilmJson> filmJsons = response.body();
                filmItemList.clear();
                for (FilmJson filmJson : filmJsons) {
                    filmItemList.add(new FilmItem(filmJson));
                }
                initUi();


            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<FilmJson>> call, Throwable t) {


        }
    });


}

private void initUi() {
    if (filmAdapter == null) {
        filmAdapter = new FilmAdapter(getActivity(), filmItemList, (FilmAdapter.FilmAdapterEvents) getActivity());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(filmAdapter);
    } else {
        filmAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


}
```

}

**FilmAdapter**

```
public class FilmAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FilmAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
private Context context;
private List<FilmItem> filmItems;
private FilmAdapterEvents filmAdapterEvents;


public FilmAdapter(Context context, List<FilmItem> filmItems, FilmAdapterEvents filmAdapterEvents) {
    this.context = context;
    this.filmItems = filmItems;
    this.filmAdapterEvents = filmAdapterEvents;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_film, parent, false);
    return new MyViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.textView.setText(filmItems.get(position).getTitle());
    holder.imageView.setImageResource(filmItems.get(position).getImg());
    holder.btnAbout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            filmAdapterEvents.onFilmClicked(filmItems.get(position));
        }
    });

    holder.btnFav.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (filmItems.get(position).getFav_status().equals("0")) {
                filmItems.get(position).setFav_status("1");
                holder.btnFav.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite_red_24dp);
                Toast.makeText(context, filmItems.get(position).getTitle() + filmItems.get(position).getDescription() +
                        filmItems.get(position).getId() + filmItems.get(position).getFav_status() + filmItems.get(position).getImg(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            } else {
                filmItems.get(position).setFav_status("0");
                holder.btnFav.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite_grey_24dp);
            }
        }
    });


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return filmItems.size();
}


static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private ImageView imageView;
    private TextView textView;
    private Button btnAbout;
    private Button btnFav;

    MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.filmImg);
        textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.titleFilm);
        btnAbout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnAbout);
        btnFav = itemView.findViewById(R.id.favBtn);

    }

}

public interface FilmAdapterEvents {
    void onFilmClicked(FilmItem filmItem);
}
```

}
**Инициализация Retrofita**

```
public class MovieApp extends Application {
public MovieService movieService;
private static MovieApp instance;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    instance = this;
    initRetrofit();
}

public static MovieApp getInstance() {
    return instance;
}

private void initRetrofit() {
    HttpLoggingInterceptor httpLoggingInterceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    httpLoggingInterceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
    OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(httpLoggingInterceptor)
            .build();

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .baseUrl("https://my-json-server.typicode.com/Sorulai/MyMoviesPlaceholder/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    movieService = retrofit.create(MovieService.class);


}
```

}

**FilmJson**

```
public class FilmJson {
public int id;
public String title;
public String fav_status;
public String description;
```

public int img;
}

**FilmItem**

```
public class FilmItem {
private int id;
private String title;
private String fav_status;
private String description;
private int img;

public FilmItem() {
}

public FilmItem(FilmJson filmJson) {
    this.id = filmJson.id;
    this.title = filmJson.title;
    this.fav_status = filmJson.fav_status;
    this.description = filmJson.description;
    this.img = filmJson.img;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getFav_status() {
    return fav_status;
}

public void setFav_status(String fav_status) {
    this.fav_status = fav_status;
}

public int getImg() {
    return img;
}

public void setImg(int img) {
    this.img = img;
}
```

Comment: Посмотрите этот ответ https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/645239/%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-recyclerview-no-adapter-attached-skipping-layout

Comment: Я уже много что попробовал, все равно не работает(